# Elasticsearch-6.x norms false not working

Tags: elasticsearch

That is what I have Done:

**First:**
`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/log_20180419"`

**Second**

> ```
> curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/log_20180419/_mapping/_doc" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
>     {
>       "properties": {    
>         "title": {
>           "type": "text",
>           "norms": false
>         }
>       }
>     }
>     '
> ```

**Third**

> ```
>     #I insert data with python client : elastisearch-py
>     from elastisearch import Elastisearch
>     es_conn = Elastisearch()
>     content_tmp = "acxzcasiuchxzuicbhasuicgzyugas%s"
>     for i in range(10000):
>         result = content_tmp % i
>         es_conn.index(index="log_20180419", body = {"title":result}, doc_type="_doc")
> ```

**Forth**
I Query It

> ```
> curl -X GET "localhost:9200/cdn_log_20180419/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>     "query": { 
>         "match":{
>
>
>
>   "title":"dasuioczxuivcaduciqanbcaiushcauinhauincsaincdjkxzcbyquiwbjkfcznkajsbcjkzxhcuiasbcjkzxchjdsfasckjbjak9999"
>         }
>     }
> }
> '
> ```

**Result is**

> ```
> {
>   "took" : 1,
>   "timed_out" : false,
>   "_shards" : {
>     "total" : 5,
>     "successful" : 5,
>     "skipped" : 0,
>     "failed" : 0
>   },
>   "hits" : {
>     "total" : 1,
>     "max_score" : 7.2293553,
>     "hits" : [
>       {
>         "_index" : "cdn_log_20180419",
>         "_type" : "_doc",
>         "_id" : "oDR99mIBBZEcRu0i7LlO",
>         "_score" : 7.2293553,
>         "_source" : {
>           "title" : "dasuioczxuivcaduciqanbcaiushcauinhauincsaincdjkxzcbyquiwbjkfcznkajsbcjkzxhcuiasbcjkzxchjdsfasckjbjak9999"
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```

You can see, it still has _score file in result, I get Confuse with it ?
The Doc is here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html

Answer (score 0):

The norm is only one part of scoring. The norm covers the field length norm and index-time boosting (if you are using that), but term frequency and inverse document frequency (TF/IDF) are independent of it.

If you don't need / want scoring for your query, look into [boolean filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) or [constant score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html).